# Javascript: can't play wav file

Tags: javascript, audio

Based on code from StackExchange, I've witten code to open a wav file.  The wav file itself is a valid file, because it plays properly with a Python program I have.  But the javascript functions don't work. The sound file is located in the same folder as my html file.

```
<div id="play_or_pause_or_exit">    
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button" id="play"       style="display:inline-block;">Play table</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button"  id="pause" style="display:inline-block;">Pause table</button> 
<button onclick="cancelAudio()" type="button"  id="cancel" style="display:inline-block;">Exit tables</button>
```

```
<script>
var audio;

function setupAudio(){
var audio = new Audio('plus1_071016_Alex.WAV');
}

function playAudio(){
    audio.play();
}   

function pauseAudio(){
    audio.pause();
}

function cancelAudio(){
    audio.pause();
sound.currentTime = 0;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: because of the `var` keyword inside the `setupAudio` function, this AudioElement will be declared only in the scope of this function, and then inaccessible to anyone. Remove this keyword if you want to populate the global `audio` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the first lines of yout script:

```
var audio;

function setupAudio(){
    var audio = new Audio('plus1_071016_Alex.WAV');
}
```

You are masking the global variable audio with a variable with the same name into the setupAudio function. In this way your Audio object will be not accessible to the helper functions *playAudio*, *pauseAudio* and *cancelAudio*. I'm assuming that somewhere in your code, not shown in your specimen, you will call the setupAudio function.

A quick and *real* dirty solution: remove the var keyword into the function and voilà: you polluted your global environment but your code should work.

I would follow a slightly different route, using a simple module pattern:

#### the css

I prefer to have the styling somewhere in the head away from the element tags: they are distracting to me

```
<style>
    #play_or_pause_or_exit > button { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

#### the HTML

I have reformatted your button tags to adapt to the cramped textarea here on stackoverflow ;-P, removed the inline styling and added a disabled attribute, to prevent the user to click on the buttons before the Audio is ready.

```
<div id="play_or_pause_or_exit">    
    <button onclick="Player.play()" 
            type="button" 
            id="play"
            disabled>Play/Resume table</button>
    <button onclick="Player.pause()" 
            type="button"
            id="pause"
            disabled>Pause table</button> 
    <button onclick="Player.stop()" 
            type="button"
            id="cancel"
            disabled>Exit tables</button> 
</div>
```

#### the Javascript

Somewhere at the bottom of the body I would put this script:

```
var Player = (function (audiourl) {

    var audio = new Audio(audiourl);

    [].forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll("#play_or_pause_or_exit > button"),
        function(x) {
            x.disabled=false;
        });

    return {
        "play": function() { audio.play(); },   
        "pause": function() { audio.pause(); },
        "stop": function() {
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
        },
    };
})("plus1_071016_Alex.WAV");
```

Player now is a IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression) that create an object encapsulating your audio resource with *play*, *pause* and *stop* methods to control resource.

Notice the audio url is at the bottom of the declaration now and it is loaded, as you may have guessed from the function expression name, as soon as the generation function is defined.

The global environment is still polluted but just by a single object that encapsulate the helper functions an the resource to play. A single point of access vs four functions and a resource variable.

Comment: Thank you.  When I fixed up my code it still didn't work.

Comment: What I needed to do was convert my wav file -- which doesn't seem to work with new Audio() into an mpg file and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have an entry point ... what is calling your setupAudio() ?  this will get you up and running

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

 // var audio = new Audio("plus1_071016_Alex.WAV");
 // var audio = new Audio("http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/a12.mp3");                 

 var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/audio-experiments/examples/elon_mono.wav");
  
function playAudio() {
    audio.play();
}   

function pauseAudio() {
    audio.pause();
}

function cancelAudio() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
}

</script>
    <body>
<div id="play_or_pause_or_exit">    
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button" id="play" style="display:inline-block;">Play/Resume table</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button"  id="pause" style="display:inline-block;">Pause table</button> 
<button onclick="cancelAudio()" type="button"  id="cancel" style="display:inline-block;">Exit tables</button> 

</body>
</html>
```