# playing sound on click event with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />

</head>
<body>

  <audio id="sounds" loop= "false" volume = "60">
    <source src="sounds/clap.wav" id="A" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="sounds/boom.wav" id="S" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="sounds/hihat.wav" id="D" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="sounds/kick.wav" id="F" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="sounds/snare.wav" id="G" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="sounds/ride.wav" id="H" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="sounds/tom.wav" id="J" type="audio/wav">
  </audio> 

<div class="keys">
  <div class="key">
    <button id="common1" class="key_link" type="submit">CLAP</button>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <a href="#" id="common2" type="button" class="key_link">BOOM</a>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <a href="#" id="common3" class="key_link">HIHAT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <a href="#" id="common4" type="submit" class="key_link">KICK</a>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <a href="#" id="common5" type="submit" class="key_link">SNARE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <a href="#" id="common6" type="submit" class="key_link">RIDE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <a href="#" id="common7" type="submit" class="key_link">TOM</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('common1'); // 

button.addEventListener('click', myPlay); 

function myPlay() {
    var a = document.getElementById('A');
    a.play();
} ;
```

First one is a button, and the rest are anchor tags. Because I was just not sure with what it will work. If it will not work with anchors, that's okay with me, but it's not working with button too.

I also used the `onclick()` with button tag. But it didn't work either. Then i read somewhere that using event listeners is a better practice. So i am trying to implement it by event listeners.

Comment: can you specify your problem?Also show your relevant code here..

Comment: You are calling `play` from the wrong html tag element, and you are not using the `source` tag element correctly. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to include the audio tags. Instead you can just say in javascript what audio you want to play.

```
function myPlay(){
    var audio = new Audio("sample.mp3");
    audio.play();
}
```

When you execute this function the audio will play.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. But don't this method work with wav files ? 
Because either it doesn't or the wav files that i have are corrupted. I just downloaded an mp3 file and placed it there, and it worked. And here i am, messing with myself from the morning, why isn't this working !!

Comment: @Shubham https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710972/javascript-cant-play-wav-file

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the wrong element with `document.getElementById`. The id of your audio tag is `sounds`, but you are trying to get it with the id `A`.

Change

```
function myPlay() {
    var a = document.getElementById('A');
    a.play();
};
```

To

```
function myPlay() {
    var a = document.getElementById('sounds');
    a.play();
}
```

Comment: But then how will i associate clap sound to button with id ''A''. ?
How will event listener know which file to play with click event ?

Comment: @Shubham The sources are not what is getting played; the audio is what is getting played. The browser decides which source is most suitable to be played.

Comment: But they are different sounds. If browser decides that it will play "'boom" sound on ''clap'' button, then what is the point ?

Comment: @Shubham You need to place the source inside a different audio tag then. You do not seem to understand how the `audio` tag works.

Comment: Yes, the reason to have multiple `source` tags inside an `audio` tag is so that the browser can choose one that it is able to play (like ogg vs mp3, etc). You shouldn't have different sounds inside of the same `audio` tag. Each sound should have its own `audio` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example, https://jsfiddle.net/nerdvoso/46f7rxbs/1/

Following code:

```js
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');

var playSound = function() {
    audio.play();
};

playBtn.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){audio.pause()}, false);
```

```html
<audio id="audio" src="https://freewavesamples.com/files/Roland-JV-2080-101-Bass-C2.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Update, https://jsfiddle.net/nerdvoso/46f7rxbs/33/

```js
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');
var nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
var prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');

var soundSelected = document.getElementById("audio1");

var playSound = function() {soundSelected.play();};

var stopSound = function() {soundSelected.pause();};

var nextSound = function() {
  if(soundSelected.nextElementSibling){
    soundSelected.pause();
    soundSelected.currentTime = 0;
    soundSelected = soundSelected.nextElementSibling;
  }
};


var prevSound = function() {
  if(soundSelected.previousElementSibling){
    soundSelected.pause();
    soundSelected.currentTime = 0;
    soundSelected = soundSelected.previousElementSibling;
  }
};

playBtn.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', stopSound, false);
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSound, false);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSound, false);
```

```html
<div id="playList">
    <audio id="audio1" src="https://freewavesamples.com/files/Roland-JV-2080-101-Bass-C2.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio id="audio2" src="https://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-V50-Metalimba-C2.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Play sound by dedicated buttons, [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/nerdvoso/46f7rxbs/46/)

```js
var playSoundBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("playSound");

var playSound = function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-sound");
    var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++){
        sounds[i].pause();
        sounds[i].currentTime = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById(attribute).play();
};

for (var i = 0; i < playSoundBtn.length; i++) {
    playSoundBtn[i].addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio1" src="https://freewavesamples.com/files/Roland-JV-2080-101-Bass-C2.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="audio2" src="https://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-V50-Metalimba-C2.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<hr>
<button class="playSound" data-sound="audio1">Sound 1</button>
<button class="playSound" data-sound="audio2">Sound 2</button>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked. Can you also tell me how to make the audio file play only once per click. In my case, when i click it just sets on loop, till i refresh the page and then it stops. I want it to play only once and then stop.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `<source>` html tag is not to point to different audio content, but same audio content with different format so the browser can choose which format is more appropriate.

So you should have something like this:

```
<audio id="clap" loop= "false" volume = "60">
    <source src="sounds/clap.wav" id="A" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
<audio id="boom" loop= "false" volume = "60">
    <source src="sounds/boom.wav" id="S" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
...
```

And if you want to offer different formats for the same sound you could have something like this:

```
<audio id="clap" loop= "false" volume = "60">
    <source src="clap.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="clap.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

And you should be doing:

```
var clap = document.getElementById("clap");
clap.play();
```

Take in consideration that it is the `<audio>` html tag from the one you can call `play()`, not from `<source>`.

Comment: The thing is, these wav files which i have, are not working. I tried to play an mp3 file with two methods, and it played both times.  Problem is with wav file.

Comment: Also can you please tell me how to stop the audio file, after it has been played once. I don't want it to repeat itself. I have already set loop = "false" , but that's not working.

Comment: @Shubham You can call `pause()` to stop the audio. I recommend you to go step by step, first fix the code and play an audio you are sure you can play, and then, try to figure out why the .wav file is not playing

Comment: It worked. I fixed the code and tested it with both mp3 and wav file. 
The files that i have , in the above code,  must be corrupted.